# Proof of natural number property

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

Can someone check my proof for the result $m<n$ is equivalent to $l+m<l+n$

Proof: We define for every $l,m$ belong to the naturals that $l+m=s_l(m)$ and $m<n$ is defined as $m$ being strictly a subset of $n$

We need to show that $s_l(m)<s_l(n)$

We show by induction on $m$ that for every $l,m$ fixed that $s_l(m)<s_l(n)$

If $m=0$ then $s_l(0)=l$ which is certainly showing $s_l(0)<s_l(n)$. Need to show this hold for every $l$ belonging to the naturals. The case $l=0$ is trivial. Suppose $s_l(0)<s_l(n)$ for some $l$ and $ n $ belonging to the naturals. Then $s_l(0')=s_l(0)'<s_l(n)'$ where we define $n'$ as the successor of $n$. By Induction, $s_l(0)<s_l(n)$.

Now suppose for some $m<n$, $s_l(m)<s_l(n)$ has been established for every $m,n$ belonging to the naturals. Then for $m',n'$ and every $l$ belonging to the naturals we have:

$s_l(m')=s_l(m)'<s_l(n)'$ as needed. By MI, $s_l(m)<s_l(n)$ holds for every $m,n$ belonging to the naturals

Comment: Are you only supposed to use PA? Or what is the context?

Comment: What does PA mean?

Comment: The context is showing this property of the naturals' arithmetic operations.

Comment: By PA do you mean the Peano axioms? If so no I can not use those.